# I'm Trying to install the pip on python3 on Linux, but everytime i try to install it by the terminal, it print to me " Unable to locate python3-pip"

Tags: python, ubuntu-21.04

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 OS.

I've tried several type of in-line terminal install like:

curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

( following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/it_it/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html)

sudo apt install python3-pip

sudo apt isntall idle-python

apt-cache search pip |  grep python

But none of these commands work...

I've also tried to opem python on my terminal typing: python3, and it works...

but when i type: pip list or something like this which contains, terminal gave me the error

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip list`

Comment: Better not to install `pip`, or anything else, in your system Python. Use virtual environments instead.

Comment: @JaredSmith /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

Comment: Then it isn't installed. As Karl Knechtel suggests, best way is to install in virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 21.10 is EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). You should upgrade to 22.04. For details, see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/301745) on Ask Ubuntu.